# Difficulty in getting Shift Value in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently my table structire for table SHIFT is as follow:

```
ID   Name       Start    End 
1    Shift1     06:00    14:00
2    Shift2     14:00    22:00
3    Shift3     22:00    06:00
```

Now I pass parameter to this query in hour like 11 or 15 or 22 or 03

For that parameter, I would like to get the result that in which shift the passed hour will reside.

So if I pass 11, it shoud give me Shift1. If I pass 23, it should give me Shift3.

Following query that I wrote works fine for any value from 07 to 21, it is giving me blank value and for obvious reasons.

```
select * from MII_SHIFT
where '[Param.1]' >= left(START,2) and '[Param.1]' <  left(END,2)
```

Can anyone help me how can I change the query so that I can get proper response for 22,23,00,01,02,03,04,05.

Thanks

Comment: why not store the values without the :00 and converting them to int, then you can do easier calculations

Comment: `Start` and  `End` are strings or date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM shift
WHERE 
     (    left(START,2) > left(END,2)
     AND  ('[Param.1]' >= left(START,2) OR '[Param.1]' <  left(END,2))
     )
OR   (    left(START,2) < left(END,2)
     AND  '[Param.1]' >= left(START,2) AND '[Param.1]' <  left(END,2) 
     )
```

[image]

I answer a similar answer a litle time ago.

- Shorts `start < end` (5-9): the value need be between start and end
- Jacket `start > end` (10-4): the value is `< start` or `> end`

Comment: a little explaining could help a long way

Comment: That isn't going to work too well with those string literals all over the place.

Comment: I include some explaining. And this should work. But as @SeanLange suggest you should save those value as `Date` or at least as `INT`. The main problem is those comparasion cant use index so can impact perfomance later.

Comment: I think you just missed () in the OR condition in the first clause of where.

Comment: Hope I still get the correct answer after fix the `()` ? your answer looks like mine.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is most likely to convert the times into dates, and if the end date is earlier than start, then add one day. You could use time datatype as input too, instead of just hour, but this is now an example with int:

```
declare @hour int, @date datetime

set @hour = 3

set @date = convert(datetime, convert(varchar(2), @hour) + ':00', 108) 

select Name
from (
  select Name, 
    [Start] as Start1, 
    case when [End] < [Start] then dateadd(day, 1, [End]) else [End] End as End1,
    case when [End] < [Start] then dateadd(day, -1, [Start]) else [Start] End as Start2, 
    [End] as End2   
  from (
    select Name, convert(datetime, [Start], 108) as [Start], convert(datetime, [End], 108) as [End]
    from Table1
  ) X
) Y
where ((Start1 <= @date and @date < End1) or (Start2 <= @date and @date < End2))
```

Edit: added 2nd start / end columns to the derived table to handle second part of the shift.

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b965/6)

Comment: You could also use other ways like a view, or computed columns to get the strings you have into dates, or maybe even store them as dates

Comment: IF I pass 05 or 04, this query does not give Shift3 as output. Instead gives BLANK.

Comment: Of course, the start needs the second part too. Made small re-write and added 2nd start / end columns

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are stored as strings, then this is pretty easy:

```
select s.*
from shifts s
where (start < end and right('00' + @param1, 2) >= start and right('00' + @param1, 2) < end) or
      (start > end and (right('00' + @param1, 2) >= start or right('00' + @param1, 2) < end))
```

This assumes that `@param1` is a string.  The `right()` is used to left pad the string with zeroes.  If that is already true, then the code would be even simpler.

EDIT:

With padding, this simplifies to:

```
select s.*
from shifts s
where (start < end and @param1 >= start and @param1< end) or
      (start > end and (@param1 >= start or @param1 < end))
```

Comment: only issue with this result is if I pass 14, it gives me Shift1. It should actually give me Shift2. Same for 06 and 22. It is giving me previous shift.

Comment: @SohamShah . . . You question is ambiguous, because it is not clear to which shift the bounds should belong.  Simply changing the inequalities fixes that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thankk you all. With the hep from all of your refrences, I was able to build the query which gave me appropriate results.

Query is as foolow:

```
SELECT Name FROM  SHIFT WHERE 

(LEFT(START,2) < LEFT(END,2) AND '[Param.1]' >= LEFT(START,2) AND '[Param.1]' < LEFT(END,2)) 

OR

(LEFT(START,2) > LEFT(END,2) AND ('[Param.1]' >= LEFT(START,2) OR '[Param.1]' < LEFT(END,2)))
```